# How to replace with NAN no more than 30% of the values with the specified flag in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have such dataset (example)

```
dat=structure(list(Y = c(2282L, 2565L, 2242L, 2109L, 2704L, 2352L, 
2492L), is_red_ndvi_v_down = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "no"), ndvi_v_down = c(0.032460447, 0.028369653, 0.017094017, 
0.016972906, 0.015228979, 0.020649285, 0.028151986), is_red_mtci_vi_max = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"), mtci_vi_max = c(0.459463725, 
0.624581753, 0.573445082, 0.478436429, 0.299561108, 0.446878491, 
0.818814539), is_red_ndvi_d85down = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", 
"yes", "yes", "no"), ndvi_d85down = c(159L, 157L, 150L, 150L, 
172L, 178L, 153L), is_red_rgvis_vi_min2 = c("yes", "yes", "no", 
"yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), rgvis_vi_min2 = c(0.606465651, 0.6024961, 
0.665637406, 0.657639244, 0.630343941, 0.641025641, 0.644292757
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

It contains a `Y` variable and several predictors.
data structure

```
  $ is_red_ndvi_v_down : chr "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" ...
  $ ndvi_v_down : chr "0.032460447" "0.028369653" "0.017094017" "0.016972906" ...
  $ is_red_mtci_vi_max : chr "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" ...
  $ mtci_vi_max : chr "0.459463725" "0.624581753" "0.573445082" "0.478436429"
```

`is_red text` prefix , means a value has a `yes` or `no` flag, followed by a variable that contains the values.
For example `is_red_ndvi_v_down` here are text flags, and next `ndvi_v_down` is already the values for the flags

I am doing the following algorithm:
If FOR ALL ROWs of a particular observation, the value “no” is found in more than 3 variables, then replace all values opposite `no` in this row with `NA`.
For example, relatively speaking, in row number 10 more than two predictors have the value `no`, then all values opposite `no` in this row are marked as NA.

- we do not touch the values opposite `yes` flag
  IMPORTANT: dataset contains 265 rows; no more than 30% of rows with `NA` are allowed.
  Therefore, if I see that 80 rows out of 265 already have `NA` in more than 2 variables
  then there is no need to replace anything opposite `no`, leave `no` in the remaining row

i try do so

```
no_count <- apply(dat, 1, function(row) sum(grepl("no", row)))

rows_to_replace <- which(no_count > 3)

num_rows_to_replace <- length(rows_to_replace)

if (num_rows_to_replace > round(0.3 * nrow(dat))) {
  dat[rows_to_replace, grepl("no", names(dat))] <- NA
}
```

but as a result, in a number of variables 104 row are replaced instead of 80

```
> paste("Number of rows replaced:", num_rows_to_replace)
[1] "Number of lines replaced: 104"
> paste("Acceptable number of NAs:", round(0.3 * nrow(dat)))
[1] "Acceptable number of NA: 80"
```

This means that in 104 rows the flag `no` occurs in more than two variables
In my case, i need 104-80=24 rows not changed by NA.

In simple terms, after the code has seen that 80 row have already become NA, then there is no need to mark the remaining 24 rows in any way.
My code constantly marks 104 rows. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it

I didn’t see any of the suggested topics with my specifics

Thanks for your valuable help

Comment: you reference row 10, but don't include row 10...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you want *all* values in a row to be NA even if a "yes" is present, or whether you only want three NAs. The first option NAs *all* vaues where "no" >= 3. The second option, which I'm guessing is the one you want, only NAs values if "no" >= 3 *AND* if "no" is present in the previous column. This distinction is demonstrated in row 5 of the results shown below. Note the .3 value returns 79.5 so you may need to change `n() * .3` to `ceiling(n() * .3)` or `nrow(df1) * .3` to `ceiling(nrow(df1) * .3)` if you want the threshold to be 80. In the sample df, row 109 is the last row where there are 3 "no" values *AND* is <= 30% of observations.

Sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Y = 1:265,
                 is_red_ndvi_v_down = c(rep(c("no", "no", "yes"), 88), "yes"),
                 ndvi_v_down = round(runif(265, 0, 1), 2),
                 is_red_mtci_vi_max = c(rep(c("no", "yes", "no"), 88), "yes"),
                 mtci_vi_max = round(runif(265, 0, 1), 2),
                 is_red_ndvi_d85down = c(rep(c("no", "yes", "no", "no"), 66), "yes"),
                 ndvi_d85down = sample(150:178, 265, replace = TRUE),
                 is_red_rgvis_vi_min2 = rep(c("no", "no", "yes", "no", "no"), 53),
                 rgvis_vi_min2 = round(runif(265, 0, 1), 2))
```

This option returns all NA even if only three NAs present (i'm guessing you don't want this):

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(no_count = rowSums(across(everything(), ~ .x == "no")), # Get count of "no" values
         no_gte_3 = ifelse(no_count >= 3, 1, 0), # Define rows with >= 3 "no" values
         no_cutoff = cumsum(no_gte_3)) %>% # Assign cumulative value of "no" rows
  mutate_at(vars(-starts_with(c("is_red", "Y"))), # Select value cols
            list(~if_else(no_gte_3 == 1 & no_cutoff <= n() * .3, NA, .))) %>% # Use new columns to NA data
  select(-starts_with("no")) # Drop temporary columns

df1[c(1:5, 109:114), ]
Y is_red_ndvi_v_down ndvi_v_down is_red_mtci_vi_max mtci_vi_max is_red_ndvi_d85down ndvi_d85down is_red_rgvis_vi_min2 rgvis_vi_min2
1                 no          NA                 no          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
2                 no        0.37                yes        0.06                 yes          151                   no          0.72
3                yes        0.57                 no        0.75                  no          170                  yes          0.35
4                 no          NA                 no          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
5                 no          NA                yes          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
109               no          NA                 no          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
110               no        0.60                yes        0.22                 yes          154                   no          0.29
111              yes        0.98                 no        0.42                  no          172                   no          0.50
112               no        0.73                 no        0.33                  no          155                   no          0.43
113               no        0.36                yes        0.86                  no          168                  yes          0.61
114              yes        0.43                 no        0.18                 yes          169                   no          0.93
```

This option adds NAs only if preceding row value == "no" (guessing *this* is what you want). Note the change in values in row 5.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(no_count = rowSums(across(everything(), ~ .x == "no")),
         no_gte_3 = ifelse(no_count >= 3, 1, 0),
         no_cutoff = cumsum(no_gte_3))

for(i in which(names(df1) %in% names(df1[, grepl("is_red", names(df1))]))) {
  
  df1[,i+1] <- ifelse(df1[,i] == "no" & 
                        df1$no_gte_3 == 1 & 
                        df1$no_cutoff <= nrow(df1) * .3,
                      NA, df1[,i+1])
  
}

df1 <- df1 %>%
  select(-starts_with("no"))

df1[c(1:5, 109:114), ]
Y is_red_ndvi_v_down ndvi_v_down is_red_mtci_vi_max mtci_vi_max is_red_ndvi_d85down ndvi_d85down is_red_rgvis_vi_min2 rgvis_vi_min2
1                 no          NA                 no          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
2                 no        0.37                yes        0.06                 yes          151                   no          0.72
3                yes        0.57                 no        0.75                  no          170                  yes          0.35
4                 no          NA                 no          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
5                 no          NA                yes        0.17                  no           NA                   no            NA
109               no          NA                 no          NA                  no           NA                   no            NA
110               no        0.60                yes        0.22                 yes          154                   no          0.29
111              yes        0.98                 no        0.42                  no          172                   no          0.50
112               no        0.73                 no        0.33                  no          155                   no          0.43
113               no        0.36                yes        0.86                  no          168                  yes          0.61
114              yes        0.43                 no        0.18                 yes          169                   no          0.93
```